How can I extract comments from Word documents *and* match them up with the highlighted text and the full sentence in which the comments appear?
Note: This  question was originally marked as a duplicate of this one. It's related, but I don't think it's an exact duplicate because my question asks how to extract the comment and the highlighted text the comment is attached to and the full sentence in which the comment appears. I've edited the question to make this clearer.
I'm working on a project where I'm parsing the XML of a Word document using BeautifulSoup. I have a document that has some edited content that's been tracked with Track Changes, and it also has a comment. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in MS Word.

The XML structure of the Word document is stored in a file called document.xml. It looks like this (I've removed the namespace information to cut down the length):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document ...>
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="60DD2CCF" w14:textId="6685D8F2" w:rsidR="00B57B76" w:rsidRDefault="00971CF4">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Here is sentence 1. Sent</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Smith, Jordan" w:date="2024-09-07T16:50:00Z" w16du:dateUtc="2024-09-07T22:50:00Z">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00F67107">
          <w:t>en</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:ins>
      <w:del w:id="1" w:author="Smith, Jordan" w:date="2024-09-07T16:50:00Z" w16du:dateUtc="2024-09-07T22:50:00Z">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00F67107" w:rsidDel="00F67107">
          <w:delText>ne</w:delText>
        </w:r>
      </w:del>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">ce 2 is </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:commentRangeStart w:id="2"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>this one</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="2"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:commentReference w:id="2"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>. Now, here is sentence 3.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00B57B76">
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="720"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>

The comment text is stored in a file called comment.xml. It looks like this (I've removed the namespace information to cut down the length):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:comments ...>
  <w:comment w:id="2" w:author="Smith, Jordan" w:date="2024-09-07T16:40:00Z" w:initials="SJ">
    <w:p w14:paraId="179CEA47" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00971CF4" w:rsidRDefault="00971CF4" w:rsidP="00971CF4">
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:annotationRef/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:color w:val="000000"/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Some comment here</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:comment>
</w:comments>

I'd like to parse the XML files to pull out different elements. I'm using BeautifulSoup to get most of what I need, but I'm totally stuck on how to

Extract the comment, and
Extract the highlighted text the comment is attached to, and
Extract the full sentence in which the comment appears.

So, for the example above, my expected output would be

Comment: Some comment here
Highlighted text: this one
Sentence: Sentennece 2 is this one.

Is there a way to do this for every comment that appears in a Word doc?
Like I mentioned, I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse the document.xml file for other information, but I'm totally stuck on how to get BS to do what I've described here. I've looked into the docx library, but it doesn't appear to do anything with comments or edits that have been tracked with Track Changes. I've also tried using the docx2python library, which makes extracting comments easy. But I don't think it would allow me to match up the comment to the full sentence in which the comment appears.

beautifulsoup has a limited implementation of xpath, lxml would be better I think

...my question asks how to extract the comment and the highlighted text the comment is attached to and the full sentence in which the comment appears.  The duplicate link does address the first two of those questions.   To get from the highlighted text to its encompassing full sentence is a third completely different question that would require NLP (or brittle punctuation-based matching).
